# Right way of creating SQL query on pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm using the `pandas` dev version as of today (9 May 2014).

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) state that

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```

However, as I understand the `pandas` interface requires me to do

```
from pandas.io import sql
eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:////path/to/file.db')
sql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myid = {0};".format(myid), eng)
```

Do I have to use `SQLAlchemy` directly to avoid injecting strings, or is there a better alternative I haven't thought about yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pandas` also has an execute method that uses parameters as in the `sqlite3` module.

```
sql.execute(sql, con, cur=None, params=None, flavor='sqlite')
Execute the given SQL query using the provided connection object.
...
params : list or tuple, optional
    List of parameters to pass to execute method.
```

Unfortunately, it does not have a lot of the functionality present in the `read_sql` method, such as `parse_dates` and returning the results as a `DataFrame` with column names, index, etc.

**EDIT:**

Oh, the `params` argument do work in the `read_sql` method! :)